# Appium Webdriver Import Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver, appium

Building a basic Appium test in Java for Android.

When I run the code, it gives me an exception error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
>
> driver cannot be resolved
>
> driver cannot be resolved
>
> driver cannot be resolved to a variable
>
> at tests.AppiumTest.main(AppiumTest.java:50)

I have triple checked my jar files, all of them appear to be included and I'm not missing any but when I hover over the driver text, the import Webdriver option does not appear.

Code below:

```
package tests;
 
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;


import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
 
public class AppiumTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "Redacted"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.vending");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");
        
        // Instagram: com.instagram.android/com.instagram.android.activity.MainTabActivity
        // Facebook: com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity
        
        try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    
    //Added 5 seconds wait so that the app loads completely before starting with element identification
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    //Find Google Play element using ID property and click on it
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.vending:id/search_box_idle_text")).click();
    
    //Find 'Google Play Store' element and set the value Google
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.vending:id/search_box_text_input")).sendKeys("Google");
    
    //Press Enter key from Keyboard using any of the below methods
    ((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).pressKeyCode(66);
    }
 
}
```

Screenshots of imported jar files:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7QYc.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwTwA.png)

Comment: where have you declared the driver variable?

Comment: There is no declaration of Your driver, maybe somewhere else?

Comment: Added the driver declaration, I am now getting a socket exception error:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

It calls out the Android Driver. Thoughts?

Comment: To clarify, I'm running this on a physical device, not an emulator but I am only connected via cable, I'm not doing a wireless connection.

Comment: I commented out the thread.sleep try and catch section, it's now working. Is there a way to make this work? I'd like to have the pause to make sure everything loads properly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all You didn't show where AndroidDriver is declared.

Second thing is that I don't see in Your dependancies Appium, You just have selenium imported.

> appium.io

You should have something like this in your pom, if using maven:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/6.0.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My dependancy:

[image]

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried adding the driver declaration, I am now getting a socket exception error:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

It calls out the Android Driver. I don't think your solution would avoid this issue?

Comment: To clarify, I'm running this on a physical device, not an emulator but I am only connected via cable, I'm not doing a wireless connection.

Comment: I commented out the thread.sleep try and catch section, it's now working. Is there a way to make this work? I'd like to have the pause to make sure everything loads properly.

Comment: you can use explicit wait for that.webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(appiumDriver, 30);
        webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));